# can't access object elements after pushing into 2d array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-maps

This Json Data from an Ajax call

```
{
    "VehicleID": 1,
    "Tracks": [{
        "TrackID": 1,
        "trackPoints": [{
            "lat": 36.25514030456543,
            "lng": 33.501180542295344
        }, {
            "lat": 36.255140304562,
            "lng": 33.5011805422952
        }, {
            "lat": 36.255140304561,
            "lng": 33.5011805422951
        }]
    }, {
        "TrackID": 1,
        "trackPoints": [{
            "lat": 31.25514030456543,
            "lng": 31.501180542295344
        }, {
            "lat": 31.255140304562,
            "lng": 31.5011805422952
        }, {
            "lat": 31.255140304561,
            "lng": 31.5011805422951
        }]
    }]
}
```

using google maps
two  for loops for iterating over tracks and points in each track,
I'm printing most of what I do into the console

```
for (var i = 0; i < numtracks; i++) {
     var numPoints = result.Tracks[i].trackPoints.length;
     arr[i] = new Array(numPoints); //creating 2d array for points
     console.log("*********Array number " + i + " Got created" + "and its lenght is " + arr[i].length + "   *******************");
     console.log("Lenght of track #" + i + " Points => " + numPoints);
     console.log("array lenghth for Points track #" + i + " => " + arr[i].length);
```

The second loop for acessing points

```
for (var j = 0; j < result.Tracks[i].trackPoints.length; j++) {
    var x = result.Tracks[i].trackPoints[j].lat;
    var y = result.Tracks[i].trackPoints[j].lng;
    console.log("x= " + x + " for #" + j + "  Point");
    console.log("y= " + y + "  for #" + j + "  Point");
```

I'm passing data into google maps API

```
var p = new google.maps.LatLng(x, y);
console.log("p befor push lat for the " + p.lat());
console.log("p befor push lng for the " + p.lng());
```

after pushing data into arr[i] .

```
arr[i].push(p);
//when acessing arr[i][j].lat();is not recgnising it
console.log("track #" + i + " , point #" + j + "pushed into array x= " + arr[i][j].lat() + " ,y=" + arr[i][j]);
```

This is the output from the console

```
array lenghth for tracks => 2 trackss:96
Tracks lenght : 2 trackss:97
*********Array number 0 Got createdand its lenght is 3   ******************* trackss:110
Lenght of track #0 Points => 3 trackss:111
array lenghth for Points track #0 => 3 trackss:112
x= 36.25514030456543 for #0  Point trackss:116
y= 33.501180542295344  for #0  Point trackss:117
p befor push lat for the 36.25514030456543 trackss:119
p befor push lng for the 33.50118054229529 trackss:120
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined
```

Comment: When your creating the array with `var arr = new Array(N)` your creating an array with `N` undefined elements. So say `N=3` your array looks like `[undefined,undefined,undefined]`. Pushing to that array will append the new value, so `arr.push("Lorem");` will yield an array that looks like `[undefined,undefined,undefined,"Lorem"]` and accessing element `arr[0]` returns `undefined` instead of `"Lorem"`

Answer (score 1):

Try initializing `arr` like this:

`arr[i] = [];`

And then adding the `p` object like this:

`arr[i][j] = p;`